Mixed Logit - Identification of beta/sigma
Since MXL is invariant to scale (utility is ordinal), we only identify $\beta/\sigma$, not $\beta$ or $\sigma$ independently. But is it possible to use the estimated $\hat{\sigma}$ from the regression to find an implied estimate of $\beta$?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
